# How to find maximum number of occurrences for a character in a cell in a column in a CSV table in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to find the maximum number of occurrences of '/' (a slash) in a cell in a column in a CSV file. Here's the table below. It has hundreds of rows.

| Person Full Name | Person CRD Number | ID Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jack Johnson | 32 / 54 / 57 / 87 | 5686 |
| John Johnsen | 11 / 22 | 6589 |
| Luke Peterson | 34 | 6978 |
| Kyle Garcia | 63 / 24 / 83 | 8957 |

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '/Users/myname/Downloads/tabularShell.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(data, index_col=0)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)['Person CRD Number']

df2 = df1.value_counts('/')

print(df2)
```

The output should be 3 because the maximum number of occurrences of '/' is 3 in a cell in the "Person CRD Number" column in the table shown above.

Thank you!

Comment: .str.count("/").max()

Comment: Use `df['Person CRD Number'].str.count('/').max()`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) for this. For each item in the column, it returns how many of the specified character are in that colum. `.max()` will then select the largest value.

```
>>> df['Person CRD Number'].str.count('/').max()
3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(max(df['Person CRD Number'].str.count('/')))
```

output:

```
>>> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you better control if you want to do more operations on your count

```
import pandas as pd

# Ignore these lines, it is just to build the dataframe
data = [['Jack Johnson', '32 / 54 / 57 / 87', '5686'],
        ['John Johnsen', '11 / 22', '6589'],
        ['Luke Peterson', '34', '6978']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['Person Full Name', 'Person CRD Number', 'ID Number']

# Define a small function to count the char in a string
def count_char(string, char=r'/'):
    return string.count(char)

# Apply the function to the CRD number and store in a new column
df['count'] = df['Person CRD Number'].apply(count_char)

# Get the maximum from the count
print(df['count'].max())
```